# Convert a few columns in the table to a resultset of name, value pair rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table like this

Table1

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5 Col6 Col7 Col8
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
2    2    3    4    5    16   17   18
3    2    3    4    5    26   27   28
4    2    3    4    5    36   37   38
```

I want the data to be converted in this format

```
Col1   DerivedCol1  DerivedCol2
1      Col6         6
1      Col7         7
1      Col8         8
2      Col6         16
2      Col7         17
2      Col8         18
3      Col6         26
3      Col7         27
3      Col8         28
4      Col6         36
4      Col7         37
4      Col8         38
```

**Edit**: One more important aspect in the question is that i dont know how many columns that i am going to choose to make them as Name, Value pairs and that might change at run time.

Comment: what have you tried? People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: Well I haven't written any code yet. I gonna have a table that ll the list of columns that i ll make them as name, value pairs and then planning to get a comma separated version of Col6, Col7, Col8 and then do a split and join. Just check if there is a better version. There is no point writing code if i dont have a good idea and i never really expect ppl to write code for me. Just checking with experts here if this can be done better !

Comment: @Mitch Wheat : Why this unnecessary lecture. If you are not ready to answer, please pass on..

Comment: @Bragboy: You call one line a lecture? This is a standard response. This site is to help you; not to do your work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build something like the following in Dynamic SQL

```
WITH pvt (Col1 , Col2 , Col3 , Col4 , Col5 , Col6 , Col7 , Col8 )
AS
(

SELECT 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,2,3,4,5,16,17,18 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,2,3,4,5,26,27,28 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,2,3,4,5,36,37,38
)

SELECT Col1, DerivedCol1 ,DerivedCol2
FROM  pvt
UNPIVOT
   (DerivedCol2  FOR DerivedCol1   IN 
      (Col6 , Col7, Col8  )
)AS unpvt;
```

Returns

```
Col1        DerivedCol1   DerivedCol2

1           Col6               6
1           Col7               7
1           Col8               8
2           Col6               16
2           Col7               17
2           Col8               18
3           Col6               26
3           Col7               27
3           Col8               28
4           Col6               36
4           Col7               37
4           Col8               38
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be the better one ! would have to check for performance between your answer and Thomas's answer. What is your general opinion about the performance comparisons between using a PIVOT and the one that Thomas just answered.

Comment: @Baaju - I'd guess that they will probably be similar on that front. Would be interested if you discover any differently.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Col1, 'Col6', Col6
From Table
Union All
Select Col1, 'Col7', Col7
From Table
Union All
Select Col1, 'Col8', Col8
From Table
```

There is no dynamic means of doing this other than to build the SQL statement in code.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look an pivot/unpivot [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)